When do we have $\int |f(x,x)|\,dx\leq \sup_{y}\int |f(x,y)|\,dx$
Under what assumptions on $f\colon\mathbb R \times\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ does the inequality $$\int |f(x,x)|\,dx\leq \sup_{y}\int |f(x,y)|\,dx$$ hold?
Attempt at proof. Suppose $f$ is integrable and continuous, and that $x\mapsto \sup_y|f(x,y)|$ is integrable. We have $|f(x,x)|\leq \sup_y|f(x,y)|$ for all $x$. So integrating we obtain $$\int |f(x,x)|\,dx\leq \int\sup_y|f(x,y)|\,dx.$$ Now by definition of the supremum there exists a sequence $(y_n)$ such that $|f(x,y_n)|\rightarrow\sup_y|f(x,y)|$. So, by the dominated convergence theorem, $$\int\sup_y|f(x,y)|\,dx=\int\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|f(x,y_n)|\,dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int |f(x,y_n)|\,dx.$$
But then clearly, by definition of the supremum, $$\int|f(x,y_n)|\,dx\leq \sup_y\int|f(x,y)|\,dx$$ for all $n$. So, in particular, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int |f(x,y_n)|\,dx\leq \sup_{y}\int |f(x,y)|\,dx.$$
Thus we have shown the inequality we want to prove, if $f$ satisfies our conditions.
Please do let me know if this proof holds.

I mean, if $f(x,y)$ is defined to be $1$ when $x=y$ and $<1$ when $x\neq y,$ then this would not be true. So something like $f(x,y)=e^{-(x-y)^2}$ would be a counterexample. The right side is equal for each $y$ and finite then, but $+\infty$ for the left side.

The proof is probably false, but one condition might be that Hessian exists and is negative-semi-definite when x=y.

@ThomasAndrews The OP seems to be operating under the assumption that $x\mapsto \sup_y \vert f(x,y)\vert$ is integrable.

I guess a simpler  example might be $\frac1{1+y^2}\cdot \frac1{4+(x-y)^2}.$

$(y_n)$ depends on $x$, no? So I think jumping from the limit on the outside to the supremum may be where this is going wrong. Unless I am mistaken everything preceding that is fine

Counter-example.
If $$f(x,y)=\frac1{1+y^2}\frac1{1+4(x-y)^2}$$ then we can ignore absolute values, since $f$ is positive, and $f(x,x)=\frac1{1+x^2},$ so $$\int_{\mathbb R} f(x,x)\,dx=\pi,$$
and $$\begin{align} 
\int_{\mathbb R} f(x,y)\,dx&=\frac1{1+y^2}\int \frac1{1+4(x-y)^2}\,dx\\
&=\frac1{1+y^2}\int \frac1{1+4u^2}\,du\quad\quad(u=x-y)\\&=\frac\pi2\frac1{1+y^2}\\&\leq\frac\pi2.
\end{align} $$
Your error would appear to be that $y_1,\dots$ are different for each $x,$ as noted by a commenter. For each $x,$ there is a sequence $y_1,\dots,$ but you can't be sure that a single sequence $y_n$ works for all $x.$
If we take instead $f_1(x,y)=e^{-y^2}e^{-4(x-y)^2},$ we get, for fixed $x,$ the maximum value is at $y=\frac45x.$
That example will ensure $g(x)=\sup_y f_1(x,y)$ has $\int g(x)\,dx<+\infty.$

Oh never mind .

Might as well make my comment into an answer. For each $x$ there does exist a sequence $(y_n)$ such that $|f(x, y_n)| \to \sup_y |f(x, y)|$, but you have suppressed dependence on $x$. There is no reason why this $(y_n)$ should be uniform in $x$ (in general, unless the supremum is attained at $\pm \infty$, the maximiser will depend on $x$). Using Thomas Andrews' example $f(x, y) = e^{-(x - y)^2}$, the maximum with $x$ fixed is attained at $y = x$ so you'll have $y_n \to x$ (taking logs in $e^{-(x - y_n)^2} \to 1$, you have $(x - y_n)^2 \to 0$), hence in this case the sequence must be different for each $x$.
If we write $(y_n(x))$ instead, to make the dependence on $x$ clear, we reach:
$$\int |f(x, x)| dx \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \int |f(x, y_n(x))| dx$$
Since $y_n(x)$ is not necessarily constant in $x$, this integral on the RHS is not of the form $\int |f(x, y)| dx$ for some fixed $y$, and so there is no reason for it to be $\le \sup_y \int |f(x, y)| dx$.

I suppose you should ensure that $y_n(x)$ (hence $x \mapsto f(x, y_n(x))$) is measurable as well...
